# This port does not accept the dimensions (or orientation) specified by the output signal

Tags: simulink, dimension, mismatch

I am building a model on simulink and having a Problem with Dimension mismatch.
I would like to implement the equation of Exponential wieghted Moving Average Algorithm which is in the attached Image, with simple blocks.

I am having a mismatch at the Memory block. I don't know why. I simply put it to get the sample before the recent one.

EWMA Algorithm:

[image: EWMA Algorithm]

Comment: You've left out the important bit.  What's to the right of the image that you've shown?  It looks like something there is expecting a vector and not getting it.  What you've shown (with a Scope instead of what you have omitted from the image) works.

Comment: @Phil Goddard Now its working but i am having another Problem. I changed the mean block to be the running mean because this is how it Needs to be averaged but i am having this error: All sample times for this block must be discrete.Continuous sample time is not allowed. I added an unbuffer before the mean block but actually it didn't Change the continuous samples to discrete ones.. it is converting from Frames to samples..One other Thing i checked is the variable step size in the simulink configuration but it did not solve the Problem. Do you have an idea how can i solve that?. Thx in advance

Comment: The signal being fed into the mean block must be discrete.  The easiest way to do this is to put a sample rate into the summation block that feeds it, or to put a Zero-Order Hold block onto that signal.  You may also want/need to use a fixed-step solver.

Comment: @ Phil Goddard. Thanks Phil, I realised that yesterday and I have put a Zero-Order Hold block and it works fine, now I am facing this Problem where I want to use the Transport Delay Block which only accepts continuous Signal, but the Input now is Fin (Fixed in Minor Step).. How can i convert it to Continuous data.. I would like to divide this Input which is a Bitrate into several Bitrate per Slot then add the Transport delay.. so using the divide block screws it totally.. Do you know how can i solve this.. Thanks in Advance